# Import many static Strings at once

Tags: java, string, command-line, import, static

How can I import many static strings at once? With bundles or something?

like:

```
import java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
```

in only one command.
Do I have to put them in Boolean class in a bundle?

Comment: BTW I suggest using your IDE to manage the imports. This can save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the wildcard import:

```
import static java.lang.Boolean.*;
```

Remember to use `import static` as this is importing static members

Comment: ... and static members are the only thing you *can* import from a class.

Answer (score 3):

`Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` are not `String` but `Boolean`.
In the actual question you want to import static fields from a class located in the `java.lang` package.
Importing them is helpless as the `java.lang` classes don't need to be imported.
So `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` can be declared without any import.

Whatever, you can use a wildcard for the last part as you want to import statically all members of a class :

```
import static java.lang.Boolean.*;
```

Now declaring members of the class without specifying the class is possible :

```
boolean isFoo = TRUE || FALSE;
```